# Converting an NSString* to char?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, char

How can I convert a NSString* into a char?

EDIT:
Thanks to Vladimir for getting me there!

```
NSString *myString = @"HelloWorld";
const char *stringAsChar = [myString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: See [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class reference - you're probably interested in **Getting Characters and Bytes** and **Getting C Strings** sections.

Comment: Thanks, should have gone there first! ;)

Comment: How is this specific to cocoa-touch? @Fasttracks

Comment: nsstring is a part of cocoa touch :)

Comment: @ing0: Typically if you want a `char*` you want to use `[NSString UTF8String]` instead of using the `[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]`.

Comment: To add some nitpicking: this is not "casting". This is more "converting".

Comment: True, didn't really think about it like that. I suppose you don't need to force it to convert like a cast would...

Comment: But it formates to (null)

Answer (score 68):

Simple to transfer

```
const char *cfilename=[stringobject UTF8String];
```

Comment: And what if I need to change this variable?

Comment: @user2083364 char *cfilename = strdup([stringobject UTF8String]); Now you can change.

Comment: why is the `const` needed?

Comment: @Honey `UTF8String` returns `const char *`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411189-utf8string?language=objc